# python string formatting

Tags: python, string, format

I need some help with the Python's new string formatter. Basically, I want the outer curly braces to not escape the string replacement field.

This works:

```
foo = 'bar'
print '{%s}' % foo
```

But, this doesn't:

```
foo = 'bar'
print('{{0}}'.format(foo))
```

Desired output:

'{bar}'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> print('{{{0}}}'.format(foo))
'{bar}'
```

The outer pair of doubled `{{` and `}}` are copied literally to the output, leaving `{0}` to be interpreted as a substitution.

Comment: Ha, sometimes I tend to over complicate things. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`{{` is an escaped `{`, but you still need `{0}` as the placeholder, thus:

```
print('{{{0}}}'.format('bar'))
```