# Python: how to run a command while using a defined variable?

Tags: file, python-2.7, directory

I'm a beginner with Python and I'm trying to list the contents of a directory which is defined as a variable but to no avail.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

location = "/home/itaig/testdir"
command = os.system('ls -l')," location"
```

My aim is to count the number of files in the location and print the number.

How can it be achieved?

Edit #1:

In bash I'd do `ls -l $location | wc -l` , what would be the equivalent in Python?

In any case, I've looked at the links from the comments but wasn't able to get it to work... can you please show me an example?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533700/python-string-formatting

Comment: Your command seems odd: It should read `os.system("ls -l " + location)`. But for listing a directory you can use the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), which is a bit easier to handle than calling a system command.

Comment: os.system('ls -l {0}'.format(location)) - unix
os.system('dir -l {0}'.format(location)) - windows

Although it may not be relevant for you, using commands will make this platform specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use os.listdir. 
This is platform independent as the os module will handle the low level work

```
print len(os.listdir(location))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the good old `os.popen` function:

```
p = os.popen('ls -l %s' % location)
nb_lines = 0
while p.readline():
  nb_lines += 1
```

Comment: why downvoting? It answers the question and provides and example of string formatting at the same time, and it shows how to read output from a command too